# SQLAlchemy ORM imperative mapping: INSERT with foreign key won't work without loading related object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm using imperative mapping, I've a many to one relation, I would like to insert a new Parent object with relation to existing Child knowing its id, without loading Child data in advance.

```py
    from typing import Optional
    
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, Table, create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
    
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    from sqlalchemy.orm import registry
    
    mapper_registry = registry()
    
    
    @mapper_registry.mapped
    @dataclass
    class Child:
        __table__ = Table(
            "child",
            mapper_registry.metadata,
            Column(
                "id",
                Integer,
                primary_key=True,
            ),
        )
        id: int
    
    
    @mapper_registry.mapped
    @dataclass
    class Parent:
        __table__ = Table(
            "parent",
            mapper_registry.metadata,
            Column(
                "id",
                Integer,
                primary_key=True,
            ),
            Column("child_id", Integer, ForeignKey("child.id"), nullable=False),
        )
        __mapper_args__ = {
            "properties": {"child": relationship("Child", lazy="joined", innerjoin=True)}
        }
        id: int
        child_id: int
    
        child: Optional[Child] = None
```

Ex. I want to add new Parent with child.id = 7 with one INSERT:

```sql
    INSERT INTO parent (id, child_id) VALUES (1, 7);
```

but this code

```py
    url = "postgresql://postgres:example@localhost/test"
    engine = create_engine(url)
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)
    parent = Parent(id=3, child_id=7)
    with Session() as session:
        with session.begin():
            session.add(parent)
```

throws error psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "child_id" violates not-null constraint

Using declarative method instead the statement `session.add(parent)` works correctly doing the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

solved in [this discussion](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7949),

> `Parent.child` supersedes the `child_id` setting and resolves as a
> NULL for child_id

solution:

```py
class Parent:
    ...
    child: Optional[Child] = field(init=False)
```